# Check for certain item in Tkinter tree

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I want to check if a certain item is in a tkinter tree. How do I do that? I tried the code below:

```
name='hi'
if name in tree.get_children():
   print 'found it'
```

Even though there is an item hi found it is never printed. How can I fi fix my code.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to populate the tree? i.e. the `tree.insert()` method you use to put the `'hi'` element into the tree? Your code seems to work for me, but its important to use the tree element identifier, not the text.

Answer (score 0):

First, grab the node you want to check and store it into a container of your choice. Ex:

```
nodeId = tree.focus()
```

Next you will want to grab the child (note don't actually grab a child) and store that into a container as well. Ex:

```
child = tree.get_children(nodeId)[0] \\only grabbing the first child
```

Finally, you will want to do the actually checks against the phrase 'hi'. Ex:

```
if tree.item(child, option='text') == 'hi':
   print 'found it'
```

This will help you check only the first child in the tree. Put the `child = tree.get_children(nodeId)[x]` inside a loop where `x` is the count variable of the `for` loop.

Disclaimer: This will only help with the logic behind what you are doing.

Source: [TKinter-Tree-Demo](http://pyinmyeye.blogspot.com/2012/07/tkinter-tree-demo.html)